# Yellow Tint in new laptop

Tags: display, dell-latitude, laptop-display

I have newest Latitude 5490 with 8th gen i7 and 16gb of RAM.

The screen of my laptop is little bit yellowish in comparison to my previous laptop (Latitude 5480). I have updated all the drivers and tried all the conventional methods available on YouTube like :

```
-- setting different RGB in color management I have tried selecting sRGB2.1 profile.
-- changing color setting in Intel Graphic control like contrast , hue options.
-- turning on off , night mode.
```

but none worked ,
can anyone help me please its urgent.

Comment: Unless you use a hardware colorimeter, you're never going to know which was correct, if either. Most laptops are shipped way out of true, over-punchy colour, over-contrast. Colorimeter is your only real fix.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.